# What can be done with NF in an awk code block or function?

Tags: awk, posix

Reference: [The POSIX standard for the `awk` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

One thing I really miss in `awk` is the ability to join an array with a delimiter, like with the `join` command in Perl, typically done for immediate output.

Instead, I end up with writing code like

```awk
for (key in array)
    joined_string = (joined_string ==  "" ? array[key] : joined_string "," array[key])

print joined_string
```

or

```awk
joined_string = array[1]
for (i = 2; i <= length(array); ++i)
    joined_string = joined_string "," array[i];

print joined_string
```

However, `awk` may do this for me if I change the current fields:

```awk
OFS="," # (would probably do this in BEGIN)

n = 0
for (key in array)
    $(++n) = array[key]

print
```

I believe that this is perfectly legal.  However, this will produce garbage in the output if the current input record has more fields than the `array` array has entries (the "garbage" would be data from the input file). It would therefore be nice to be able to do

```awk
OFS = "," # (would probably do this in BEGIN)

n = 0
for (key in array)
    $(++n) = array[key]

NF = n
print
```

I can't find any text in the standard saying that modifying `NF` is allowed, but neither any text saying that it's not allowed or that it invokes undefined behaviour.  The information I *can* find is that `getline` *sets `NF`*. This does not say that I'm not allowed to write my own function or code block that resets `NF`, and it gives a precedence for doing this with the existence of the `getline` "function".

It's also stated that *assigning to `$0` is allowed* and that this resets `NF`.  Does that mean that the following code would be better?

```awk
OFS = "," # (would probably do this in BEGIN)

$0 = ""
n = 0
for (key in array)
    $(++n) = array[key]

print
```

Twofold question:

1. Is setting `NF` allowed?
2. Would that last piece of code be the correct way of joining an array with a delimiter for output?

Comment: FWIW, [the GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields) has this: "**CAUTION**: Some versions of awk don’t rebuild $0 when NF is decremented." So, for portability's sake the second might be better.

Comment: @muru Ah, yes, I do recall seeing that, now that you mention it.

Comment: would the order be always consistent `for (key in array)` ? I thought it wasn't guaranteed.. and yeah, modifying `NF` is gawk specific

Comment: @Sundeep no, modifying `NF` isn’t gawk-specific, at least mawk supports it too. [The One True Awk](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) doesn’t.

Comment: @Sundeep No, the order of the keys, when accessing them that way, is not guaranteed to be ordered in any particular way. That's usually not an issue though (or I would keep track of the order using an index array).

Comment: issues with NF assignment is on my long list of issues I plan to raise one day to the austin group. Here, regardless of what POSIX says assigning to NF is not portable in practive. You can always do `$0 = ""` before though. IIRC `length(array)` is not standard either.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42875915/how-do-you-convert-an-array-to-a-string-in-awk

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No, `length()` is only defined as giving the length of a string. I was a bit sloppy in my code, admittedly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know there is no *standard* text documenting the side-effects of setting `NF`, or even whether setting it is allowed. The Gawk manual (also published as *Effective `awk` Programming*), which says that [it attempts to document Awk in general](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Preface.html#Preface) and not (only) the GNU implementation, [includes the following](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html#Changing-Fields):

> Decrementing `NF` throws away the values of the fields after the new value of `NF` and recomputes `$0`. (d.c.)

with the caveat

> **CAUTION:** Some versions of `awk` don’t rebuild `$0` when `NF` is decremented.

The “(d.c.)” mention means that this is a [“dark corner” of Awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Glossary.html#Glossary), *i.e.* one which is poorly documented (or not at all) and where behaviour can vary from one implementation to another.

POSIX defines special variables as

> variables that are set by *awk*

but it doesn’t specify whether they can be set by programs (as a general rule). Some of the variables’ specifications do mention that they can be modified (see `ARGC`, `ARGV`), others that the consequences of changing them are implementation-defined (`ENVIRON`), others still don’t mention anything but are “obviously” intended to be modified by the program (`OFS` etc.).

In `NF`’s case, experimentation gives a partial answer:

- modifying `NF` works as documented in GNU Awk, and `mawk` also behaves in the same way;
- changes to `NF` in [The One True Awk](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) are preserved, but don’t cause `$0` to be re-computed.

So I would say that

1. Setting `NF` is allowed, but might not have any side-effects other than setting the value.
2. Since setting `$0` *is* specified by POSIX, the last variant is correct according to the specification. (It’s arguable whether it’s *the* correct way, since it loses `$0`.)

The function in [How do you convert an array to a string in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42875915/4500798) is interesting, but as defined it relies on GNU Awk extensions and is thus not an answer to this question.

(Other variables which can be set, somewhat surprisingly, include `NR` and `FNR`, including in TOTA. `FILENAME`, however, can’t be set, or rather, setting it clears its value.)